# Mostrar resultado de consulta de forma diferente SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT pr_products.product AS PRODUCT, pr_varieties.variety AS VARIETY, pr_grades.GRADE, SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS QUANTITY
FROM pf_harvest
INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
INNER JOIN pr_grades ON pr_grades.id = pf_harvest.id_grade
WHERE pf_performance.status = 100
AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
AND pf_harvest.date = '2017-03-22'
GROUP BY pf_harvest.id_product, pf_harvest.id_variety, pf_harvest.id_grade
ORDER BY pf_harvest.id_product, pr_varieties.variety, pf_harvest.id_grade;
```

que me muestra el siguiente resultado:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRODUCT     |     VARIETY     |     GRADE      |     QUANTITY  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV1      |     GRADE1     |     1000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV1      |     GRADE2     |     5000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV2      |     GRADE1     |     2000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1       |     ROSE1V1     |     GRADE1     |     3500      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

es posible mostrar el resultado de la consulta de la siguiente manera?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  PRODUCT     |   VARIETY   |  GRADE1  |  GRADE2 |  TOTAL         |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ROSEV1    |  1000    |  5000   |  6000          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ROSEV2    |  2000    |    0    |  2000          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1      |   ROSE1V1   |  3500    |    0    |  3500          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

he intentado cambiar la consulta pero no he podido y quisiera saber si es posible, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

gracias

Comment: te refieres para quitar los duplicados ?

Comment: No, si te fijas en GRADE, me muestra la consulta que hay dos: GRADE1 y GRADE2, y quisiera mostrar en el resultado la cantidad que hay en GRADE1 y GRADE2 por PRODUCT y VARIETY, tal cuál como se muestra en la segunda tabla

Comment: ¿Sólo tendrías dos posibilidades de Grade (Grade 1 y Grade 2) o podrías tener en algunos casos Grade 3, Grade 4, Grade N...? Es importante a la hora responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Sí, podrían haber mas posibilidades @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el resultado como lo describes, tienes desplegar las cantidades en dos sumas condicionales:

```
SELECT pr_products.product AS PRODUCT, 
       pr_varieties.variety AS VARIETY, 
       pr_grades.GRADE, 
       SUM(IF(pr_grades.GRADE='GRADE1',pf_harvest.quantity,0)) as GRADE1,
       SUM(IF(pr_grades.GRADE='GRADE2',pf_harvest.quantity,0)) as GRADE2,
       SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS TOTAL
FROM pf_harvest
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Tengo dos comentarios adicionales:

1. No estabas agrupando por pr_grades.GRADE. Si la consulta funcionaba, entonces para esta modificación debieses quitar `pf_harvest.id_grade` del GROUP BY
2. Tendrás que hacer tantas sumas condicionales como GRADES distintos tengas en tu tabla `pr_grades`.

Answer (score 0):

Estás mostrando GRADE como un campo descriptivo y QUANTITY como el valor, lo que debes hacer es mostrar el valor de GRADE1 y GRADE2 para después sumarlos, deberás reutilizar la tabla `pf_harvest` y renombrarla `pf_harvest AS GRADE1` & `pf_harvest AS GRADE2`