# Agregar totales a una tabla de acuerdo a un parámetro PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para mostrar una tabla en PHP

```
<?php

$harvest = Array ( 
       Array ( 
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE' ,
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ADELE', 
                                  'GOLD' => 160, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 0 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 160 
                                  ) ,
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ALESSO' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 1320 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 550, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 1870 
                                  ) ,
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 150 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 590 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                                  'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1' ,
                                  'GOLD' => 420 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 120 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1', 
                                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 100 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2',
                                    'GOLD' => 640, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 0, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 640 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 440, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 440, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 880 
                                   )
                    )


     );


$arrayThead = array();
      for ($i=0; $i < count($harvest) ; $i++) {
        array_push($arrayThead, array_keys($harvest[$i][0]));
      }

      $totalByProduct = array();
      foreach ($harvest as $items) {
          foreach ($items as $item) {
              if(!key_exists($item['PRODUCT'], $totalByProduct)){
                  $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']] = $item;
                  unset($totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']]['VARIETY']);
                  continue;
              }
              foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
                foreach ($values as $th) {
                  if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){

                    $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']][$th] += $item[$th];
                  }
                }
              }
          }
      }

      $arrayfoot= array();

      foreach ($harvest as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $harv) {
          foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $th) {
              if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
                  $arrayfoot[$th] += $harv[$th];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $arrayfoot= array();

      foreach ($harvest as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $harv) {
          foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $th) {
              if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
                  $arrayfoot[$th] += $harv[$th];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $arrayComplete = array();
      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayThead) ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayThead[$i]) ; $j++) {
          if($arrayThead[$i][$j] != 'PRODUCT' && $arrayThead[$i][$j] != 'VARIETY'){
            array_push($arrayComplete, $arrayThead[$i][$j]);
          }
        }
      }


      $arrayFinal = array();
      for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayComplete) ; $j++) {
        array_push($arrayFinal, $arrayfoot[$arrayComplete[$j]]);
      }

    //  exit;

      $body = '';
      $body .= '<table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;font-family:Calibri;">';
      $body .= '<thead style="background-color:#f3f4f5;">';
      $body .= '<tr>';

      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayThead) ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayThead[$i]) ; $j++) {
          if($arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'PRODUCT' || $arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'VARIETY'){
            $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;height:50px;">'.$arrayThead[$i][$j].'</th>';
          }else{
            $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;height:50px;">'.$arrayThead[$i][$j].'</th>';
          }
        }
      }
      $body .= '</tr>';
      $body .= '</thead>';
      $body .= '<tbody>';

      for ($k=0; $k < count($harvest); $k++) {
        for ($a=0; $a < count($harvest[$k]) ; $a++) {
          $body .= '<tr>';
          for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayThead) ; $i++) {
            for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayThead[$i]) ; $j++) {
              if($arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'PRODUCT' || $arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'VARIETY'){
                $body .= '<td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;">'.$harvest[$k][$a][$arrayThead[$i][$j]].'</td>';
              }else{
                $body .= '<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:right;font-size:12px;">'.number_format($harvest[$k][$a][$arrayThead[$i][$j]]).'</td>';
              }
            }
          }
          $body .= '</tr>';
          foreach ($totalByProduct as $key => $value) {
            if($value["PRODUCT"] == $harvest[$k][$a]['PRODUCT']){
              $body .= '<tr>';
              $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;font-size:12px;">TOTAL '.$value["PRODUCT"].'</th>';
              $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;font-size:12px;"></th>';

              foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
                foreach ($values as $th) {
                  if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){

                    $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:right;font-size:12px;">'.number_format($value[$th]).'</th>';
                  }
                }
              }
              $body .= '</tr>';
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $body .= '</tbody>';
      $body .= '<tfoot>';
      $body .= '<tr>';
      $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;">TOTAL GENERAL</th>';
      $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>';

      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayFinal) ; $i++) {
        $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">'.number_format($arrayFinal[$i]).'</th>';
      }

      $body .= '</tr>';
      $body .= '</tfoot>';
      $body .= '</table>';

      echo $body;
```

Necesito colocar una fila con el total de GOLD, NORMAL y TOTAL dentro de la tabla, pero de acuerdo al producto.

Si desea ver cómo funciona el código, puede copiar el código y pegarlo en esta página: [PHPTESTER](http://phptester.net/)

Necesito mostrar a la mesa algo como esto:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  PRODUCT     |   VARIETY   |  GOLD    |  NORMAL |  TOTAL         |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ADELE     |  160     |  0      |     160        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ALESSO    |  1320    |  550    |    1870        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |  ANASTACIA  |  440     |    150  |  590           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   TOTAL ROSE |             |  1920    |  700    |  2620          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1      |  ANASTACIA1 |  420     |  120    |  540           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1      |  ANASTACIA1 |  440     |    100  |  540           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL ROSE1  |             |  860     |  220    |  1080          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE2      |  ANASTACIA2 |  640     |    0    |  640           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE2      |  ANASTACIA2 |  440     |    440  |  880           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  TOTAL ROSE2 |             |  1080    |  440    |  1520          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL GENERAL|             |  3860    |  1360   |  5220          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Y siempre se cumple que las columnas numéricas son GOLD, NORMAL y TOTAL? Porque, en ese caso, ponerlas explícitamente en vez de adentro de un foreach te simplificaría un poco las cosas. Segundo, no está claro qué no te resulta por ahora.

Comment: No, pueden ser más a parte de GOLD, NORMAL, TOTAL siempre es igual

Comment: Sería bueno agregar que, dejando de lado toda la complejidad de tu abstracción, lo único que te está faltando es la lógica para no imprimir los subtotales en cada fila

Comment: Me sonaba una pregunta sobre esos datos: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58960/mostrar-resultado-de-consulta-de-forma-diferente-sql. Creo que podrías resolverlo desde tu consulta SQL... agrupando y obteniendo un resultado por cada fila con lo que quieras. Si existen las bases de datos es para algo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo, pero estoy tratando de hacerlo y no he podido! @A.Cedano

Comment: Entiendo. Pero el que no hayas podido no significa que sea imposible. Los manejadores de bases de datos cuentan con un gran número de herramientas que nos permiten obtener nuestros datos de la manera que necesitemos sin tener que pasar por obtenerlos de una manera y luego volver a tratarlos o recalcularlos en PHP. Lo que pasa es que a veces cuando ciertas tareas resultan complicadas podemos pensar también  en que quizá la forma en que está diseñada nuestra BD no es la más adecuada para responder a nuestras necesidades. Quizá el lunes podría detenerme un poco y mirarlo más de cerca.

Comment: Vale @A.Cedano, muchas gracias por tu consejo, voy a seguir revisando, gracias!